# Error: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using `Ionic 2`. The app builds an Android `apk` successfully on Windows.

I am now trying to build it for `iOS` on OSX. When I run:

```
ionic build ios
```

I get the following:

[image]

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: Is your xcode-select pointing to correct directory ?

Comment: Have you tried (re)installing Xcode?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to OSX. How do I check where it's pointing?  How do I reinstall?

Comment: @Richard: Even after four years: Maybe you can accept the answer below? Or did it not work out for you?

Answer (score 46):

You need to configure `xcode` after installation:

Open xcode, go to > preferences > locations (tab) > command line tools (dropdown) > set latest version.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me. XCode12-beta & macOS: Catalina

Comment: Me too. XCode 12.3 (12C33) & macOS Big Sur

Comment: It works for me using Xcode 13.2.1 & MacOS BigSur