# CORDOVA IOS - Error Promise Rejected when I build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-cli

I got my error when I tried to build my first iOS Cordova App.
By using this command :

> sudo cordova build ios --device

Here what my terminal output:

> CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'xcode-select: error:
>   tool \'xcodebuild\' requires Xcode, but active developer directory
>   \'/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools\' is a command line tools
>   instance\n'
>       at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

What this is error is all about?
How do I solve it?

Thank you very much!
Regards,

Daksamedia

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116584/error-xcode-select-error-tool-xcodebuild-requires-xcode/46236616

Comment: Please refer to this link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116584/error-xcode-select-error-tool-xcodebuild-requires-xcode/46236616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're facing this error and you installed XCode already, All you have to do is to...

- Open XCode
- Go To **Xcode > Preferences > Locations**
- From the Command Line Tools Select your XCode
  [image]

Answer (score 28):

I had similar issue when running ionic cordova build ios --prod. Well to solve this issue there some stuffs have to check:

First make sure you have Xcode Installed with command line tools also
If you have Xcode installed already check the version and your mac version to download the right command line tools.
Download the command line tools here [Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools)
After install it and run this command to fix the xcode-select path

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

After this run the command again. Am sure this will work for you

Comment: After downloading the "Command Line Tools" running this command resolved my error with Cordova deploying to an iOS Simulator for my Quasar (vueJS) mobile app.

Comment: Fixed my issue too.  Although I was still able to build and run within XCode before, it is certainly more convenient to be able to do so directly from the command line.